# How To Hide Taskbar and Have Programs Use Free Space

Tags: c#, windows, taskbar

I want to hide the taskbar and have any programs open use the new space from where the taskbar was. I tried to use this class.
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
public class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentHandle, int childAfter, string className, int windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    protected static int Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        }
    }

    protected static int HandleOfStartButton
    {
        get
        {
            int handleOfDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
            int handleOfStartButton = FindWindowEx(handleOfDesktop, 0, "button", 0);
            return handleOfStartButton;
        }
    }

    private Taskbar()
    {
        // hide ctor
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_SHOW);
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

I then called `Taskbar.Hide()`, however programs didn't use the new space.

Comment: Right click taskbar -> Taskbar settings -> Automatically hide the taskbar?

Comment: You should broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` using [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx). As you can see in the Docs, the hWnd parameter must be set to `HWND_BROADCAST`. This message goes to all top-level windows. The SystemParameter change notification should be `SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030`.

Comment: Could somebody please provide an example? I have been trying to figure this out but p-invoke is tricky and unsafe business.